# How to read from input and run print from a list of appropriate module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of modules that can perform several different functions such as math.py, time.py, date.py and weather.py.
I want to use user input to appropriately select form the list the answer e.g if a user keys in date today, the date.py module runs and if another input is 'what time is it?' teh time.py module runs. It should run as a continuous loop.
Please help
This is the sample code

```
import sys
import math
from dates import date
import weather
Mymodule-List = ['math','weather','date']
 words = input ('Please enter your query: ').lower()
 words2 = words[:]
 while True
 for item in words2:
statement
```

.........# this is where am stuck

I need something to rum from the modules and say like: "The time is 11:50 am. Thank you" for an input of 'what is the time' etc

Comment: Aside: those are unfortunate name choices for modules.  There are built-in modules named `math` and `time`, and they're too handy to shadow with your own.

Comment: Do you want the selected module to be imported and call a function or just the call?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
import importlib

def run_func(module_name)
    importlib.import_module(module_name)
    # some code...

# ... some code ... while ...
if name in ['math','weather','date']:
    run_func(name)
```